# how to join 3 tables in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have three tables

Item master: stores item master details

```
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT, primary key
name character varying(255),
description character(255),
price double precision,
tax double precision,
readytosales character(1) DEFAULT 'N'::bpchar,
itemgroupid integer,
uom character varying(30),
quantity double precision DEFAULT 0,
```

purchase: stores purchase details

```
purchaseid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT,
quantity double precision DEFAULT 0,
purchasemasterid integer NOT NULL,
itemid integer NOT NULL,
itemprice double precision DEFAULT 0.00,
```

sales: stores sales details

```
salesid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT,
quantity double precision DEFAULT 0,
salesmasterid integer NOT NULL,
itemid integer,
itemprice double
```

formula used to get the stock summary is

```
itemmaster.quantity + purchase.quantity -sales.quantity
```

I used the following query to get the details, but couldn't get the results

```
select im.id as itemid, 
       name as itemname,
       im.quantity as oepningquantity, 
       im.price as openingprice,
       (im.quantity * im.price) as openingbalance,
       p.quantity as purchasequantity, p.itemprice as purchaseprice,
       (p.quantity * p.itemprice)as totalpurchaseprice, 
       s.quantity as salesquanity, s.itemprice as saleprice,
       (s.quantity *s.itemprice)as totalsalesprice
from item_master as im 
  full outer join purchase as p on im.id=p.itemid 
  full outer join sales as s on im.id=s.itemid
```

Comment: Do have MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: i am using postgres

Comment: are you sure that item_master.itemgroupid doesn't correspond to the itemid in the other tables? your code looks solid, so it may be the contents of the tables and finding the right keys.

Comment: *But couldn't get the results* Would you elaborate more about the result you want? @PriyankaMasade you can use this to make formatted table https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 1):

For Example We have 3 tables.
table_1. 
table_2.
table_3.

and the table_2 and table_3 are reference by a foriegn key from table_1.
so if we join these three table together the query will look like this.

```
Select {table 1 Cols} {table 2 Cols} {table 3 Cols}
from table_1
join table_1.table_2ID = table_2.Id on (Specify Condition here)
join table_1.table_3ID = table_3.Id on (Specify Condition here)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a tiny problem with your Query.
Correct Query is :

```
   select im.id as itemid, 
   name as itemname,
   im.quantity as oepningquantity, 
   im.price as openingprice,
   (im.quantity * im.price) as openingbalance,
   p.quantity as purchasequantity, p.itemprice as purchaseprice,
   (p.quantity * p.itemprice)as totalpurchaseprice, 
   s.quantity as salesquanity, s.itemprice as saleprice,
   (s.quantity *s.itemprice)as totalsalesprice
```

_____from item_master as im ______  -------This Statement is Wrong.

```
   from item_master -- Try This One.

   full outer join purchase as p on im.id=p.itemid 
   full outer join sales as s on im.id=s.itemid
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
       select 
       im.id as itemid, 
       name as itemname,
       im.quantity as oepningquantity, 
       im.price as openingprice,
       (im.quantity * im.price) as openingbalance,
       p.quantity as purchasequantity,
       p.itemprice as purchaseprice,
       (p.quantity * p.itemprice)as totalpurchaseprice, 
       s.quantity as salesquanity, 
       s.itemprice as saleprice,
       (s.quantity *s.itemprice)as totalsalesprice
       from 
       Item master im,
       purchase p,
       sales s 
       where
       im.id=p.itemid and
       im.id=s.itemid;
```